# performance of boost::threads notify_one vs notify_all

Tags: c++, multithreading, boost, semaphore, boost-thread

I have an implementation of Semaphore to manage a shared resource using boost::threads. My implementation of the Semaphore is as shown below.

```
void releaseResource()
{
    boost::unique_lock<boost::mutex> lock(mutex_);
    boost::thread::id curr_thread =  boost::this_thread::get_id();
    // scan through to identify the current thread
    for (unsigned int i=0; i<org_count;++i)
    {
        if (res_data[i].thread_id == curr_thread)
        {
            res_data[i].thread_id = boost::thread::id();
            res_data[i].available = true;
            break;
        }
    }
    ++count_;
    condition_.notify_one();
}

unsigned int acquireResource()
{
    boost::unique_lock<boost::mutex> lock(mutex_);
    while(count_ == 0)  { // put thread to sleep until resource becomes available
        condition_.wait(lock);
    }
    --count_;
    // Scan through the resource list and hand a index for the resource
    unsigned int res_ctr;
    for (unsigned int i=0; i<org_count;++i)
    {
        if (res_data[i].available)
        {
            res_data[i].thread_id = boost::this_thread::get_id();
            res_data[i].available = false;
            res_ctr = i;    
            break;
        }
    }
    return res_ctr;
}
```

My question is regarding the performance degradation that I notice when there are more threads than the number of resources available. If I use `notify_all` to wake threads up instead of `notify_one` as shown in the `releaseResource()` code, I see that the performance improves. Has anyone else experienced something similar?

I am using **Windows 7** and **boost 1.52**.

Comment: It seems that [boost 1.52.0 implementation](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_52_0/boost/thread/win32/condition_variable.hpp) has slightly complex task in `notify_one` than `notify_all`, for `std::vector<> generations` member, `vector::erase + remove_if` in `notify_one` vs. only `vector::clear` in `notify_all`.

Comment: Thank you for the remark. Can you tell me if I can use `notify_all` instead of `notify_one` for the code specified above?

Comment: I just wanted to make a note for other users that the issue mentioned here got fixed in boost 1.53.